# How do I return 2 values from two arrays when using filter

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript code that uses forEach to loop through each array to check if it fulfils a condition. Then, it calls for another function. Note:
by looping through every element in arr1 and arr2, I'm checking if any elements in arr1 are colliding with any elements in arr2. isCollision is a function which calculates their distance if they intersect

```
arr1.forEach(x => arr2.forEach(y => isCollision(x,y)? explode(x,y): undefined));
```

Right now, I do not want it to return undefined. So I was wondering is there a way to get the x & y values so that I can map it to another function. I tried this

```
arr1.filter(x => arr2.filter(y => isCollision(x,y)).map(x,y => //do something)
```

But right now it's only returning the value of y. Is there a way for it to return both x and y?

Comment: can you also add some test data with the source array and the result you want to obtain?

Comment: `.map((x,y) => ({x,y}))`

Comment: `arr1.filter(x => arr2.filter(y => isCollision(x,y))` how is this supposed to work? You filter `arr1` to anything that's in `arr2` but...`arr2.filter` will always return an array, which is a truthy value, thus this is *equivalent* to doing `arr1.filter(_ => true)` except that the dummy predicate would be faster.

Comment: @VLAZ oh. is there another way to go about this? since I do not want it to return undefined (first code)

Comment: I'm unclear what the requrement is here. Are you trying to find the intersection of `arr1` and `arr2` based on `isCollision`?

Comment: @VLAZ by looping through every element in arr1 and arr2, im checking if any elements in arr1 are colliding with any element in arr2. isCollision is another function which calculates their distance if they intersect

Comment: @llamaro25 OK, I think I understand the problem now. I was confused because of the code. So, you want to find any pairs (or could you have more?) of `x, y` objects that collide then do a function for each of them, correct?

Comment: @VLAZ yup, that's right. If they collide, i will execute the explode function on ```x,y```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr1
 .map(x => ({x, y:arr2.find(y => isCollision(x,y)}))
 .filter(pair => pair.y !== undefined)
```

First map to {x:y} and then remove not found items.

To cast to a non-undefined type, use a another map.

```
arr1
 .map(x => ({x, y:arr2.find(y => isCollision(x,y)}))
 .filter(pair => pair.y !== undefined)
 .map(pair => pair as {x:Elem, y:Elem})
```

Comment: this works but since i'm using typescript this changes the type of y from Elem to Elem | undefined :/

Comment: I wish typescript could figure that out... Just add a final map that casts to your expected type. `.map(it => it as {x:Elem, y:Elem} )`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all pairs of objects from `arr1` and `arr2` that match some requirement (`isCollision`) using only array methods, that's probably not going to be as pretty as doing a pair of loops. But still, it's doable - the basic idea is that you want to check each pair of objects from `arr1` and `arr2` against your `isCollision`. And to do *that* you need to go over all possible combinations between the two arrays. So, the basic steps are:

1. Generate all combinations of pairs from the two arrays
2. Filter the pairs by using `isCollision`
3. Anything you get will be colliding, so you can run whatever you want with those.

So, here is a simplified representation of the objects - they only have a `coord` property which shows their position (one dimensional for simplicity) and a `value` property. `isCollision` checks if any two objects take the exact same space. Your logic and objects would be different but that should't matter for the execution steps you need to take

```js
const arr1 = [
  { coord: 1, value: "x1" },
  { coord: 2, value: "x2" },
  { coord: 3, value: "x3" },
  { coord: 4, value: "x4" },
  { coord: 5, value: "x5" }
];

const arr2 = [
  { coord: 2, value: "y2" },
  { coord: 4, value: "y4" }
];

function isCollision(x, y) {
  return x.coord === y.coord;
}

function explode(x, y) {
  console.log(`${x.value} explodes, as does ${y.value}`);
}

arr1
  .flatMap(x => arr2.map(y => [x, y]))  //1. generate all combinations of pairs
  .filter(pair => isCollision(...pair)) //2. get only the colliding objects
  .forEach(pair => explode(...pair));   //3. run them  through the explode() function
```

Here, I use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to generate pairs - the function given to `flatMap` will generate an array of pairs itself, so if we just had `.map`, that will return

```
[
  [[x1, y2], [x1, y4]],
  [[x2, y2], [x2, y4]],
  [[x3, y2], [x3, y4]],
  [[x4, y2], [x4, y4]],
  [[x5, y2], [x5, y4]]
]
```

instead of

```
[
  [x1, y2],
  [x1, y4],
  [x2, y2],
  [x2, y4],
  [x3, y2],
  [x3, y4],
  [x4, y2],
  [x4, y4],
  [x5, y2],
  [x5, y4]
]
```

Inside [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is used to turn the pair of objects into arguments to the functions.

This can be be slightly more elegant by using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the parameters of the functions:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { coord: 1, value: "x1" },
  { coord: 2, value: "x2" },
  { coord: 3, value: "x3" },
  { coord: 4, value: "x4" },
  { coord: 5, value: "x5" }
];

const arr2 = [
  { coord: 2, value: "y2" },
  { coord: 4, value: "y4" }
];

function isCollision([x, y]) { //<-- destructuring
  return x.coord === y.coord;
}

function explode([x, y]) { //<-- destructuring
  console.log(`${x.value} explodes, as does ${y.value}`);
}

arr1
  .flatMap(x => arr2.map(y => [x, y]))
  .filter(isCollision) // <--------------------------------------|
  .forEach(explode);// <-- just passing the function reference --|
```

Anything you do will have the same complexity, since you still need to iterate through each of `arr1` and `arr2` anyway - you could only `.flatMap` directly only collisions, skipping the `.filter` step...but that just means that you need to do the `.filter` as part of the flatmap. So, this shows off all operations you'd need to do.

In this case, it might be easier to just keep your original code. It might look slightly less elegant in some ways but it works and it still does the same steps - goes through each pair of `x, y`, checks if the pair collides and it executes a function if it does.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { coord: 1, value: "x1" },
  { coord: 2, value: "x2" },
  { coord: 3, value: "x3" },
  { coord: 4, value: "x4" },
  { coord: 5, value: "x5" }
];

const arr2 = [
  { coord: 2, value: "y2" },
  { coord: 4, value: "y4" }
];

function isCollision(x, y) {
  return x.coord === y.coord;
}

function explode(x, y) {
  console.log(`${x.value} explodes, as does ${y.value}`);
}

arr1
  .forEach(x => arr2.forEach(y => {
    if (isCollision(x,y)) {
      explode(x,y)
    }
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of: [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

So you don´t have the 2nd loop of chaining methods:

```js
let a1 = [
  { x: 1, y: "y1" },
  { x: 2, y: "y2" },
  { x: 3, y: "y3" },
  { x: 4, y: "y4" },
  { x: 5, y: "y5" }
];

let a2 = [
  { x: 2, y: "y2" },
  { x: 4, y: "y4" },
  { x: 7, y: "y7" }
];

let isCollision = (
  {x: x1, y: y1}, 
  {x: x2, y: y2}
) => x1 === x2 && y1 === y2;

// Custom logic:
let explode = ({x, y}) => console.log(`Explode {x: %d, y: %o}`, x, y) || {x,y};

// You could use .reduce() instead of .filter().map() combo:
let collisions = a1.reduce((acc, p1) => a2.some(p2 => isCollision(p1, p2)) ? [...acc, explode(p1)] : acc, []);

// Explode {x: 2, y: "y2"}
// Explode {x: 4, y: "y4"}
```